# Migrated Ubuntu and EFI partition to ssd from hdd (dualboot Windows 7 + Ubuntu). Now I can't boot Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I've migrated my / and /home from hdd (sdb) to ssd (sda). Also I copied the EFI partition from hdd to sdd. (All copied using GParted for creating partitions on ssd, and then rsync for copying contents)

I was able to boot to Windows after migration, but needed firstly to update the grub menu using Grub Customizer. After deleting the EFI partition from the hdd I couldn't boot anymore windows. The os-prober or Grub Customizer don't identify Windows.

It seems that Windows grub menuentry was bound to EFI partition from the hdd. Is there a way to make it boot again using the EFI from the ssd? (the windows bootloader is still there, on the ssd).

ssd partitions:

```
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0    50G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0 130.4G  0 part /home
```

hdd partitions:

```
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb3   8:19   0   128M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0 108.2G  0 part 
└─sdb6   8:22   0 214.4G  0 part
```

sdb3 - Microsoft reserved partition

sdb4 - NTFS partition with Windows installed

sdb6 - an ext4 partition for storage

Comment: If karel's link does not solve your issue, run Boot-Repair, but just for report, do not run any fix until reviewed. Occasionally Boot-Repair's auto-fix is not best option and you need to make choices in its advanced mode. Or may need Windows repairs that Boot-Repair cannot do. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred Here is the Boot-Repair report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/R3M9jZ488D/. Until your comment i ran the Boot-Repair recommended fix, therefore purged and reinstalled GRUB among other packages like shim, os-prober and linux-headers, following the Boot-Repair guide. After that, at boot time in GRUB2 menu appeard a menuentry for Windows pointing to its boot loader from the EFI partition on the ssd, but after selection, Windows logo appears and then PC restarts.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. You should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, f12 or other key depending on brand. And may need f8 for Windows repair console or even use your Windows repair/recovery flash drive's repair mode.  Did you turn off Windows fast start up? Or did you install AHCI drivers in Windows before changing drive to AHCI in UEFI settings?

Comment: @oldfred there was a problem with the Windows installation (but it's offtopic), so i reinstalled it. The Boot-Repair solved the original question. Thanks for help)